# Retrieve an image from a website using Ruby and Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, steam, marketplace

I am trying to get an image from this website using Ruby. 
https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/M4A1-S%20%7C%20Cyrex%20(Minimal%20Wear)
So far, I have successful code to get the name of the item listed on the website:

```
 html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/'+url2))
 title = html.css('title').text
 titles = title.sub(/^Steam Community Market :: Listings for / , '')
```

Which results in "M4A1-S | Cyrex (Minimal Wear)"

(The "url2" comes from an input box on the html page that I made)

The image on the Steam Website has a class of "market_listing_largeimage".

Is there a way to also use Nokogiri to get the image src so that I can then input it into Html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image does not have that class; the `div` that the image is wrapped in does. That said,

```
html.at_css('.market_listing_largeimage img')['src']
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out!

Comment: Is this the correct syntax for the html if I want to put the retrieved src into html?   <img src=<% bookmark.pricecheck%>></img>

Comment: That will work if you are lucky, depending on the contents of the variable. `<img src="<%= bookmark.pricecheck%>"></img>` should be more robust; but you'll only be completely safe if you also do some escaping on the string. If you are using Erubis instead of ERb (default for Rails; if you aren't, you should), you can use `<img src="<%== bookmark.pricecheck%>"></img>` to be completely safe (it escapes stuff for you).